# How can I start an application(zoom client) with python?

Tags: python

A week ago, I built an application to automate the process of joining the daily Zoom meetings using pyautogui https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest . To start zoom, I would make my program click on the coordinates where zoom shortcut is located on taskbar. It was fine until today. Yesterday, by mistake, I had changed the taskbar icons' order. Therefore, my whole program crashed. So, I want to know if there is a better way of starting the zoom application with python.

Comment: Do you just want to start up the application - Zoom or also join a meeting

Comment: If you just want to open it, you can use `subprocess.call([r'path\to\executable\zoom.exe'])`

Comment: @Jonathan1609 Just tell me how to start the application rest I have done.